# Check for iVar's Names with respect to NSDictionary keys

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am parsing the values of Json object to my data model, and I am trying to figure out if there is any way to compare the name of the iVar's set for are the same with respect to dictionary keys. I am sure there is a good way to do that, but just can't find the method somehow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell what you're asking, but I think you want [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). In particular, `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` will let you pass a dictionary of property or ivar names and set them for you.